# Airflow Scheduling Issue || Daylight Saving || London Time

Tags: airflow

I have a Airflow DAG with the following code snippet:

```
from airflow import DAG
import pendulum

with DAG(
    dag_id="DLS_DAG",
    start_date = pendulum.datetime(2023, 10, 20, 5, tz="Europe/London"),
    schedule = '15,45 1 * * *',
    catchup=False,
    tags=["daylight_saving_testing"],
    )
```

The job runs at 1:15 AM and 1:45 AM London Time Daily .
On 29th, October,2023 . I saw that the job was triggered at 1:15AM ,1:45AM (both instances it finished within seconds) and then again at 1:45 AM of the repeat hour. It somehow skipped only the 1:15AM run of the repeat hour . Ideally I would have liked to skip also the 1:45AM run of the repeat hour.

Due to some other requirements I have to schedule it at London time and cannot shift it to UTC.

How can I resolve this issue. And why did airflow skip only one run of the repeat hour.

Also what happens in March when the 1AM-2AM window is completely skipped . Does Airflow trigger those jobs scheduled during that time period.